# Se donne au malade — loch

Tags: sens, histoire

Entre la première version du [livret](http://www.mediterranees.net/mythes/troie/offenbach/helene1.html) de *[La Belle Hélène](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Belle_H%C3%A9l%C3%A8ne)* (Jacques Offenbach), datée de 1864, et la version généralement donnée aujourd'hui (notamment celle que j'ai vue moi, dirigée par Marc Minkowski au Châtelet), il y a des différences. L'une d'entre elle concerne le premier mot d'une charade. On trouve dans la version moderne :

> Mon premier est le lac, chez les voisins d'Albion — *loch*

La version d'origine est :

> Mon premier se donne au malade — loch

Mais je ne comprends pas pourquoi. Le Littré, comme le TLF et les dictionnaires de l'Académie, ne donnent que le sens géographique et le sens marin… En quel sens donc le *loch* se donne-t-il au malade ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Loch" a été un [très vieux terme de médecine](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loch_%28pharmacie%29). Il vient de l'arabe et désignait une préparation destinée à soulager les voies respiratoires.

Comment: Oh, il était caché sous une autre graphie (*looch*)… merci !